# error in initializer IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.IdentityResourceMappers in .Net 7

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4

When the project is run for the first time, this error is issued when building the initial values.

**System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.IdentityResourceMappers' threw an exception.'

---

1-VerificationException: Method System.Linq.Enumerable.MaxFloat: type argument 'System.Char' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.**

2-ArgumentException: GenericArguments[0], 'System.Char', on 'T MaxFloatT' violates the constraint of type 'T'.*

**this is my data :**

```
var identityResources = new List<IdentityResource>()
               {
                    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                    new IdentityResource("profile","profile", new[]
                    {
                        ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                        JwtClaimTypes.Role
                    }),
                };

         context.IdentityResources.AddRange(identityResources.Select(m => m.ToEntity()));
```

## The Last line produces these two errors.\**

## I learn with "ASP.NET Identity with Identity Server 4 | Tutorial Part 1" in YouTube and in this video there are no errors.

Comment: I am having the same problem, except for mine is `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.ClientMappers`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
In .NET 7, there is an error for this:

```
IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Mappers.IdentityResourceMappers
```

and `IdentityServer4` should solve it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How did you wind up solving this issue?